# Remove weird space between images in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

The code below shows a simple image grid but there is spacing that I do not want, how do I remove it?
The first block is my html, the second is my css, and the third is the output.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row paddingbottom">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/fb_edit.png"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/tw_edit.png"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1"><a href="#"><img src="images/yt_edit.jpeg"></a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.paddingbottom
{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**Output**

[image: the result I get back]

Comment: change this: `<div class="row paddingbottom">` to this: `<div class="row">`

Comment: What spacing do you mean? Vertical, horizontal or both?

Comment: @manikKhurana did any of these answers helped you ? if yes please mark as correct :) I think you would like to check this tour to see how stack works. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code, it will solve problem,

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3"><img src="images/tw_edit.png"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><img src="images/tw_edit.png"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2"><img src="images/tw_edit.png"></div>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Do you mind explaining to me why this works, here is the output, just need to add some padding in between the images.

Comment: @manik khurana I reduced the size of columns and moved first column by 3 offset to align images in center i.e. 3 columns offset+6 cloumn of images + 3 columns  on right =12 columns

Answer (score 1):

set the padding to 0px. ".row div{padding: 0;}"

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the horizontal spacing between images, that's because Bootstrap uses a 12-Column layout grid. Your images are taking just 9-Columns of it (3 x 3Column divs).
Just change the class of your 3 container divs to 'col-md-4'.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row paddingbottom">
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="images/fb_edit.png"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="images/tw_edit.png"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="images/yt_edit.jpeg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are using `col-md-offset-1` that will create 1 column space in your image so just remove it and it will be fine.

**[From bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)**

> **Offsetting columns**
>
> Move columns to the right using .col-md-offset-*
>   classes. These classes increase the left margin of a column by *
>   columns. For example, .col-md-offset-4 moves .col-md-4 over four
>   columns.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row paddingbottom">
    <div class="col-md-3 "><a href="#"><img src="images/fb_edit.png"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 "><a href="#"><img src="images/tw_edit.png"></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="images/yt_edit.jpeg"></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce your division width of `.row paddingbottom:` and give

```
.paddingbottom
 {
  padding: 0%;
  }
```